# Can't import namespace package "c4d" but any other name for it works

Tags: python, import, namespaces, python-2.6

I've built myself a collection of Python libraries which I collect under the `nr` namespace. Now for a Python plugin in an application called C4D, I want to use the `nr.c4d` module, but it can't be imported. Strangely, if I rename it to anything else (eg. `nr.c4dlib`), it works!

```
+ nr.c4d\
  + nr\
    * __init__.py  # < pkgutil.extend_path() in here
    + c4d\
      * __init__.py
      * gui.py
      * ...
```

This is the code that is in each namespace `__init__.py`

```
# This is a namespace package.
try:
  import pkg_resources
  pkg_resources.declare_namespace(__name__)
except ImportError:
  import pkgutil
  __path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
```

The `nr.__path__` list seems fine, too.

```
['C:\\maxon\\Cinema 4D R16 Dev\\plugins\\procedural\\python\\nr',
 'C:\\maxon\\Cinema 4D R16 Dev\\plugins\\cloudui_frontend_r16\\devel\\nr.strex\\nr',
 'C:\\maxon\\Cinema 4D R16 Dev\\plugins\\cloudui_frontend_r16\\devel\\nr.concurrency\\nr',
 'C:\\maxon\\Cinema 4D R16 Dev\\plugins\\cloudui_frontend_r16\\devel\\nr.cli\\nr',
 'C:\\maxon\\Cinema 4D R16 Dev\\plugins\\cloudui_frontend_r16\\devel\\nr.c4d\\nr']
```

But I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "'cloudui_frontend.pyp'", line 176, in <module>
ImportError: No module named c4d
```

It might be relevant that there is a built-in module called `c4d` in the environment. What is the source of this error? How to fix it?

---

*Update* The problem seems to come from another namespace module called `nr.procedural`. It does `import c4d` at the top of the file. If that line is commented out, importing `nr.c4d` works! Also, instead of commenting out the line, I can add `from __future__ import absolute_import`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative imports caused a `None`-entry to be created for `nr.c4d` in `sys.modules` before `nr.__path__` was extended a second time. This is the issue I opened on my `localimport` repository:

> **Scenario**: `nr.procedural` does `import c4d`. If `nr.c4d` does not exist, the module will be added as a None-entry to `sys.modules`. If then `_localimport` is used to import `nr.c4d`, the module will not be found as the module cache says that the module does not exist (by the None-entry).
>
> **Solution**: `_localimport` must delete None-entries for namespace packages on `__enter__()`.

The [fix](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/localimport/commit/842d2aee2b37782441c53143d46864a597e080d4) was relatively easy.

I will  need to add `from __future__ import absolute_import` to all `nr.` sub-packages that `import c4d` though.